# Get category ID from its name in joomla?

Tags: joomla, categories

How can i get the category ID from the category name in joomla?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

`Back End site` > `Category Manager` > look at the ID column.

Did you mean programatically?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following query

```
SELECT `id` FROM `#__categories` WHERE `name` = '$name';
```